# NetSuite MapReduce - Capture Data From a Request

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a script that updates the product data in NetSuite on another system. When this occurs, I get response 200 and json with the product id on the other system. I would like to know how do I get this id (97323), as I need to set a field in the item record in NetSuite.

[image: log screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
var response = admin.post(url_produto_save, 
        {'Authorization': authorization, 'Content-Type': content_type, 'User-Agent-x': user_agent_x }, 
        bodyObject); 
log.audit({ title: 'Response Status', details: response.code }); 
log.audit({ title: 'Response Body', details: response.body });
```

Comment: Not clear at all, be more precise, what are you doing ? what do you want to do ? some codes ? what are logging ?...

Comment: This is the snippet of code where I get the responder.body. I need to give a record.load in the item and set a field with itemid (97323) that is in the response.body of the log. How do I get the value that comes from the request response?

Comment: var response = admin.post(url_produto_save,{
                     'Authorization': authorization,
                     'Content-Type': content_type,
                     'User-Agent-x': user_agent_x
                 }, bodyObject);
                 log.audit({ title: 'Response Status', details: response.code });
                 log.audit({ title: 'Response Body', details: response.body });

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you `response.body` is showing `{"status":"ok"...` when logged and you want to get the value of the `idproduto`.

If I did understand well your request, then you can try two things:

1. If the "content_type" in your request is "json", then the body
   answer will be a JSON object and you will be able to use :
   `response.body.idproduto`
2. If that didn't work, then you can parser the "body" and then use it:

   ```
   var parsedBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
   var idItem = parsedBody.idproduto;
   ```

Comment: Great! It worked. I needed this a lot. I'm new to development and learning new things every day. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of friends Tiw and B. So I'm posting the updated code snippet. Thank you all!

```
if ( response.code == 200 ) {
                var parseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
                var id_admin = parseBody.idproduto;
                log.audit('id_admin', id_admin);
                var grava_id_admin = load_itemObject.setValue({ fieldId: 'displayname', value: id_admin })
                                                     .save();
            }
```